# Different user access theri own tables through the same url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Here the url will look like

www.xxx.com/username/posts.

And I am lost here, a little bit confused, so how to to that, can anyone tell me?
Here is what I got, after you login, you will have your dashboard like www.xxx.com/your_username

And each user have their posts talbe. the url will look like
www.xxx.com/username/posts

Is there any gem or plugin for rails? Or can you just tell me how to do that?
I am new here, so I need more info here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell of your clearly not proof-read question, you want dynamic routes.

In rails, you can define routes with `:param` entries, so you can have something like (on your config/routes.rb):

```
get 'www.xxx.com/:username/posts' , to: 'posts#index'
```

And then, you can get that params in your controller like `params[:username]` so you can filter your `@posts` with:

```
@posts = Post.where(username: params[:username])
```

or, depending on your modeling

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
@posts = Post.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

Maybe you should read the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

GL & HF.

Comment: And, does facebook stored every user timeline in one table? For instance, www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx will direct you to someone's timeline, people have their own tables? What will the table look like?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to reply to this, in this case, you can have slugs for human-readable urls. A gem example: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id